# Using Python to create a (random) sample of n words from text files

Tags: python, text, random, nlp, named-entity-recognition

For my PhD project I am evaluating all existing Named Entity Recogition Taggers for Dutch. In order to check the precision and recall for those taggers I want to manually annotate all Named Entities in a random sample from my corpus. That manually annotated sample will function as the 'gold standard' to which I will compare the results of the different taggers.

My corpus consists of 170 Dutch novels. I am writing a Python script to generate a random sample of a specific amount of words for each novel (which I will use to annotate afterwards). All novels will be stored in the same directory. The following script is meant to generate for each novel in that directory a random sample of n-lines:

```
import random
import os
import glob
import sys
import errno

path = '/Users/roelsmeets/Desktop/libris_corpus_clean/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)  

for text in files:
    try:
        with open(text, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
             # number of lines from txt file
             random_sample_input = random.sample(f.readlines(),100) 

    except IOError as exc:
    # Do not fail if a directory is found, just ignore it.
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR: 
            raise 


# This block of code writes the result of the previous to a new file
random_sample_output = open("randomsample", "w", encoding='utf-8') 
random_sample_input = map(lambda x: x+"\n", random_sample_input)
random_sample_output.writelines(random_sample_input)
random_sample_output.close()
```

There are two problems with this code:

1. Currently, I have put two novels (.txt files) in the directory. But the code only outputs a random sample for one of each novels.
2. Currently, the code samples a random amount of LINES from each .txt file, but I prefer to generate a random amount of WORDS for each .txt file. Ideally, I would like to generate a sample of, say, the first or last 100 words of each of the 170 .txt-files. In that case, the sample won't be random at all; but thus far, I couldn't find a way to create a sample without using the random library.

Could anyone give a suggestion how to solve both problems? I am still new to Python and programming in general (I am a literary scholar), so I would be pleased to learn different approaches. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to split your lines into words, store them somewhere, and then, after having read all of your files and stored their words, pick 100 with `random.sample`. It it what I did in the code below. However, I am not quite sure if it is able to deal with 170 novels, since it will likely result in a lot of memory usage.

```
import random
import os
import glob
import sys
import errno

path = '/Users/roelsmeets/Desktop/libris_corpus_clean/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)
words = []

for text in files:
    try:
        with open(text, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
             # number of lines from txt file
             for line in f:
                 for word in line.split():
                     words.append(word)

    except IOError as exc:
    # Do not fail if a directory is found, just ignore it.
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR: 
            raise 

random_sample_input = random.sample(words, 100)

# This block of code writes the result of the previous to a new file
random_sample_output = open("randomsample", "w", encoding='utf-8') 
random_sample_input = map(lambda x: x+"\n", random_sample_input)
random_sample_output.writelines(random_sample_input)
random_sample_output.close()
```

In the above code, the more words a novel has, the more likely is to be represented in the output sample. That may or may not be the desired behaviour. If you want each novel to have the same ponderation, you can select, let's say, 100 words from it to add in the `words` variable, and then select 100 hundred words from there at the end. It will also have the side effect of using a lot less memory, since only one novel will be stored at a time.

```
import random
import os
import glob
import sys
import errno

path = '/Users/roelsmeets/Desktop/libris_corpus_clean/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)
words = []

for text in files:
    try:
        novel = []
        with open(text, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
             # number of lines from txt file
             for line in f:
                 for word in line.split():
                     novel.append(word)
             words.append(random.sample(novel, 100))


    except IOError as exc:
    # Do not fail if a directory is found, just ignore it.
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR: 
            raise 


random_sample_input = random.sample(words, 100)

# This block of code writes the result of the previous to a new file
random_sample_output = open("randomsample", "w", encoding='utf-8') 
random_sample_input = map(lambda x: x+"\n", random_sample_input)
random_sample_output.writelines(random_sample_input)
random_sample_output.close()
```

Third version, this one will deal with sentences instead of words, and keep the punctuation. Also, each book has the same "weight" on the final sentences kept, regardless of its size. Keep in mind that the sentence detection is done by an algorithm that is quite clever, but not infallible.

```
import random
import os
import glob
import sys
import errno
import nltk.data

path = '/home/clement/Documents/randomPythonScripts/data/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)

sentence_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/dutch.pickle')
listOfSentences = []

for text in files:
    try:
        with open(text, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            fullText = f.read()
        listOfSentences += [x.replace("\n", " ").replace("  "," ").strip() for x in random.sample(sentence_detector.tokenize(fullText), 30)]

    except IOError as exc:
    # Do not fail if a directory is found, just ignore it.
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise

random_sample_input = random.sample(listOfSentences, 15)
print(random_sample_input)

# This block of code writes the result of the previous to a new file
random_sample_output = open("randomsample", "w", encoding='utf-8')
random_sample_input = map(lambda x: x+"\n", random_sample_input)
random_sample_output.writelines(random_sample_input)
random_sample_output.close()
```

Comment: Thanx! This might do the trick for the random words sampling. However, vpekar emphasized that it would be better to use grammatical sentences instead of lines or words, so that's what I'm looking into now.

Comment: I get a 'Syntaxerror: invalid syntax' with regards to 'sentence[0] += currentSentence
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Now I get two NameErrors: name 'novel' and name 'words' is not defined.

Comment: Now I get a 'ValueError: Sample larger than population' . Even when I transform it to random.sample(listOfSentences, 50) or random.sample(listOfSentences, 10). This is strange. In my very first version of the code this was never the case with 100 lines (not sentences). Do you have an explanation?

Comment: Yeah, I know. I would be pleased if you get it figured out. However, I can naturally wait until your home ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125705/discussion-between-efferalgan-and-roel-smeets).

Comment: I suggest using a proper sentence splitter, because there are lots of special cases such as "Mr. Smith", "U.S.", etc.

Comment: It should be better now.

Answer (score 3):

A few suggestions:

Take random sentences, not words or lines. NE taggers will work much better if input is grammatical sentences. So you need to use a sentence splitter.

When you iterate over the files, `random_sample_input` contains lines from only the last file. You should move the block of code that writes the selected content to a file inside the for-loop. You can then write the selected sentences to either one file or into separate files. E.g.:

```
out = open("selected-sentences.txt", "w")

for text in files:
    try:
        with open(text, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
             sentences = sentence_splitter.split(f.read())
             for sentence in random.sample(sentences, 100):
                 print >> out, sentence

    except IOError as exc:
    # Do not fail if a directory is found, just ignore it.
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR: 
            raise 

out.close()
```

[edit] Here is how you should be able to use an NLTK sentence splitter:

```
import nltk.data
sentence_splitter = nltk.data.load("tokenizers/punkt/dutch.pickle")
text = "Dit is de eerste zin. Dit is de tweede zin."
print sentence_splitter.tokenize(text)
```

Prints:

```
["Dit is de eerste zin.", "Dit is de tweede zin."]
```

Note you'd need to download the Dutch tokenizer first, using `nltk.download()` from the interactive console.

Comment: Thanks! You are right about taking the random sentences. However, when I run your proposed code. I get 'NameError: name 'sentence_splitter' is not defined' . Is there a module where the sentence_splitter can be imported from?

Comment: Perhaps using the sentence tokenizers from nltk?

Comment: When I import nltk.data and define the variable sentence_splitter = nltk.data.load("tokenizers/punkt/dutch.pickle") , and run the code afterwards, I get the following AttributeError: 'PunktSentenceTokenizer' object has no attribute 'split'. Do you know why that is?

Comment: It should be "tokenize", not "split".

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. But now I am getting a 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object' with regards to 'sentences = sentence_splitter.tokenize(f.readlines())' Why would that be?

Comment: Try sentences = sentence_splitter.tokenize(f.read()). The argument should be a string, not a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

This solves both problems:

```
import random
import os
import glob
import sys
import errno

path = '/Users/roelsmeets/Desktop/libris_corpus_clean/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)

with open("randomsample", "w", encoding='utf-8') as random_sample_output:
    for text in files:
        try:
            with open(text, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                # number of lines from txt file
                random_sample_input = random.sample(f.read().split(), 10)

        except IOError as exc:
            # Do not fail if a directory is found, just ignore it.
            if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise

        # This block of code writes the result of the previous to a new file
        random_sample_input = map(lambda x: x + "\n", random_sample_input)
        random_sample_output.writelines(random_sample_input)
```

Comment: Thanx, this works well. Someone else suggested that I should use sentences instead of words, which is right. So now I am delving into that.